# Save a Google Chart as PNG Image with Overlays

Tags: javascript, google-visualization

Having trouble with getting the Google Charts API to save as PNG and preserve the overlays.

At the JSFiddle example below, I have it working properly on the top, and the result I'm getting as a PNG without the overlays on bottom.  I want to save with overlays as a PNG image.

http://jsfiddle.net/2nb5sjx5/

Thanks.

```
    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('line-chart-marker'));

google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', placeMarker.bind(chart, data));

google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'ready', function () {
    placeMarker.bind(chart, data);
    chart_div.innerHTML = '<img src="' + chart.getImageURI() + '">';
    // console.log(chart_div.innerHTML);
});

chart.draw(data, options);
```

Comment: there aren't any chart methods available, maybe try [html2canvas](https://html2canvas.hertzen.com/)...